# Events not displayed in fullcalendar js

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

Please any one help me to find what is going wrong in code. I used fullcalendar.js for calendar event.

I want to show the events in calendar. below is my code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(window).resize(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', get_calendar_height());
        });

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var nevent = [];
        
        nevent = document.getElementById('<%=hdnevent.ClientID%>').value;
        
       
       // alert(nevent);
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                width: get_calendar_width
            },
            width: get_calendar_width,
            height: 480,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            allDayDefault: false,

            //  events: 'JsonResponse.ashx',
            events: nevent
     });

    });
```

`nevent` value is:

```
[{ id: '2302', title: 'XXX', start: '4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM', end: '4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM', allDay: true, url: 'xxx'}]
```

but it is not displayed in calendar.
if i gave directly assign the value then it displaying the event.

Example:

```
events: [
    { 
        id: '2302', 
        title: 'XXX', 
        start: '4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM', 
        end: '4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM', 
        allDay: true, 
        url: 'xxx'
    }
]
```

pls kindly help me to rectify my error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calendar needs to be told to update after a data change. Try:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', nevent);
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

when nevent is ready.

**EDIT:**

Accept the input as JSON object not a string:

```
nevent = $.parseJSON(document.getElementById('<%=hdnevent.ClientID%>').value);
```

Note that the JSON must be in correct format with quotes like:

```
[{ "id": "2302", "title": "XXX", "start": "4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM", "end": "4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM", "allDay": true, "url": "xxx"}]
```

Comment: remove this line :  var nevent = [];  and then see what is being put in nevent from the console. I think this input might be incorrect.

Comment: if i directly assign the value to nevent instead of assigning hidden value i can able to display events in calendar. Is there problem in datatype of input?

Comment: What is the value of "document.getElementById('<%=hdnevent.ClientID%>').value;"?

Comment: the value of the input type is a string. This is your problem then. It's not a json object

Comment: [{ id: '2302', title: 'XXX', start: '4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM', end: '4/4/2014 12:00:00 AM', allDay: true, url: 'xxx'}]

Comment: how to change it to json object?

Comment: try nevent = jQuery.parseJSON(document.getElementById('<%=hdnevent.ClientID%>').value)

Comment: see updated answer. Your JSON is not in correct format. This will cause Calendar to not show.

Comment: yahoooooo its working :):):)thanks... thanks alot....  struggling for more than a week...

Comment: Just a note: last line is not needed, according to documentation `addEventSource` automatically places events on the calendar (see here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/addEventSource )

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this way in my calendar application.It seems your date format is wrong.It should be

```
[{ id: '2302', start: new Date(2014, 1, 3, 12, 0), end: new Date(2014, 4, 4, 12, 0) ,allDay: true, url: 'xxx'}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: same happened to me, the date format was wrong

Answer (score 2):

in `nevent` value, `start` (and `end`) according to documentation should be: 
"you may specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"), a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX timestamp"

so you have to convert your dates.

Comment: It should take most date formats fine. It uses MomentJS as its base for dates.

Answer (score 0):

For me some events where not showing at all because i had `timezone` param defined. Still not sure why, but they appeared when i removed this param.